# How to do rollback in spring bach for specific chunk?

Tags: spring-batch

Say I have 1000 data which is being read by reader and my chunk size is 50.In my processor after doing some business logic , deleting data from some table by calling java stored procedure and in case of deletion fail , incrementing failed-deletion count. At last when control comes to writer if failed-deletion count> 0 then I want to rollback the entire deletion for this particular chunk and this should not affect the other chunk process. Can someone please help on this? for more information please let me know.

Comment: If an exception is thrown, the chunk will roll back.

Comment: thanks @MichaelMinella , if I throw exception from writer, will rest of the chunk will get processed ?

Comment: Its working @MichaelMinella as you suggested , just one more thing as deletion is getting fail because of some data issue,so I don't want my status to be FAILED . I still want this as COMPLETED is there anyway to achieve same ?

Comment: You'll want to skip the items that cause the exception in order for the step to complete successfully.

Comment: Thanks I'll implement this.